# Spring mvc redirect to different application on different jvm

Tags: spring-mvc

My requirement is to redirection between two different apps in different JVMs.  And also transfer data between the two.  I tried using Flash Attributes, but in the controller, the attributes are null.  I tried creating an interceptor also, but even there the flash attributes are null.  Can anyone help me on how to pass attributes between two different applications?

Here is my code:
poc1 - calling application

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="flashMapManager" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("customer", customer);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Added successfully.");
        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/poc2";
    }
```

poc2 - called application

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="flashMapManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager" />
    <!-- <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"> 
        <property name="interceptors"> <list> <ref bean="requestInterceptor" /> </list> 
        </property> </bean> -->
    <bean id="requestInterceptor" class="RequestInterceptor" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <ref bean="requestInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) {
    Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils
            .getInputFlashMap(request);
    Customer cust1 = (Customer) model.asMap().get("customer");
    Customer cust = (Customer) inputFlashMap.get("customer");
    ModelAndView modelMap = new ModelAndView("showCustomer");
    System.out.println("Calling controller");
    return modelMap;
}
```

Comment: Share your workaround please.

Comment: This is the question without main skeleton. Share your Work directories so that Doc's can have look at it.

Comment: Workaround was using spring redirection and rest services to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,
Using just `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(...) -> "redirect:..."` worked as well, didn't have to "reinsert" the model attribute.

Comment: It works when redirecting to another controller within a same application.  But when moving to a different application, the flash attributes are always null.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="addcustomer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
   final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

  redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("customer", customer);
  redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message","Added successfully.");

  return "redirect:showcustomer.html"; 
 }

Comment: I have tried it and it works, but it is for the same application.  But for a different application, this does not work, when I do return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/zpoc2";  and redirect to another application "poc2" from "poc1", then the data is lost.